# Want to launch RASPIVID at startup (preview/display to HDMI) abd be able to stop RASPIVID (either by keypress or button press)

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero, raspivid

I have tried multiple ways of launching "raspivid -t 0" at startup, but there is never a decent way to stop or kill it?

Has anyone actually solved this issue?

CTRL+C only works is if I launch raspivid from a terminal, and then CTRL+C from *that* terminal. But, launching it from a simple bash/.sh does not allow that. I also tried to launch a terminal (using "x-terminal-emulator" in the .sh).

All I want to do is:

1. launch video at startup to HDMI (raspivid preview is great)
2. Be able to stop the video (if there is a need to troubleshoot and for safe shutdown, either directly on the device w/USB keyboard/mouse or via VNC)
   (3. I plan to add a power button to the setup as well for safe shutdown and boot, but I want to solve #2 above first)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `pkill raspivid`

Comment: pkill only sometimes works, and even then, only when I can get into the Pi Sero via VNC (so if the connection dies or is inaccessible for whatever reason, I'm SOL). I was getting errors that said it could not be stopped (?!) and I ended up having to pull the power plug. I then pulled the camera cable so I could deactivate raspidvip at startup (via cron). I need a nice way to stop raspidvip it without VNC as well.